# how to find a bijection from R to (0,$\infty$)?

Tags: functions

how can I find a bijection from R to (0,$\infty$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponential function $e^x$ is a bijective map from $\mathbb{R}\to (0,\infty)$.

And it has an inverse $\ln(x)$ who is bijective from $(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$